# how to include linux kernel header files

Tags: linux-kernel

I am attempting some Linux kernel development.

I have a problem in including a header file **sched.h**  (which exists in the path /usr/src/linux-3.12.26/kernel/sched, not in /usr/src/linux-3.12.26/include/linux ).

But when I "**sudo make -C  /usr/src/linux-3.12.26/  M=$(pwd)  modules**" I got the  error **"fatal error: kernel/sched/sched.h: doesn't exist"**

Here is my code:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/percpu.h>
#include </usr/src/linux-3.12.26/kernel/sched/sched.h>

int __init init_current(void){
    int cpu_num=0;
    struct task_struct *p;
    for(cpu_num=0;cpu_num<8;cpu_num++)
    {
     p=curr_task(cpu_num);
     printk(KERN_ALERT "current task on cpu %d is %d\n", cpu_num, p->pid);
    }
    return 0;
}

void __exit exit_current(void)
{
   printk(KERN_ALERT "FINISHED！\n");
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
module_init(init_current);
module_exit(exit_current);
```

There may be some errors in the code. My intention is to get the current running process in different cores.

@Santosh A .Thanks for continuing concerning my puzzle.After I changed the Makefile in /usr/src/linux-3.12.26/(see my answer above，it may not be normative,but work ),the headers I include can be found.Then I get another problem. Here is my code:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
//#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/percpu.h>
#include <sched/sched.h>
static int __init init_current(void){
int cpu_num=0;
extern struct task_struct *p;
struct rq *q;
extern struct rq * cpu_rq(int);
for(cpu_num=0;cpu_num<8;cpu_num++)
{
 q=cpu_rq(cpu_num);
 p=q->curr;
 printk(KERN_ALERT "current task on cpu %d is %d\n", cpu_num, p->pid);
}
return 0;
}

static void __exit exit_current(void)
{
 printk(KERN_ALERT "FINISHED！\n");
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
module_init(init_current);
module_exit(exit_current);
```

Here is error info:

```
/home/wison/code/current/current.c: In function ‘init_current’:
kernel/sched/sched.h:539:23: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘&’ token
 #define cpu_rq(cpu)  (&per_cpu(runqueues, (cpu)))
               ^
/home/wison/code/current/current.c:11:28: note: in expansion of macro ‘cpu_rq’
 extern struct rq * cpu_rq(int);
```

Comment: I suspect that "sched.h" is intended only to be used by code contained in closely related directories, so is not part of the include path.  What you are trying to do may not be workable for more fundamental reasons, but you *might* be able to get it to find the file simply by saying `#include <../kernel/sched/sched.h>` or even, unportably but just to see what other problems you will have, specifying the full absolute path of the file in quotes instead of angle brackets.